# Extract the time field from Pyspark column versus extracting the time field from Pandas datetime column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am migrating my code from pandas to Pyspark and I want to know how I can extract the time field from the next column :

```
df['DATE'] : 
0          2020-10-12 00:00:47
1          2020-10-12 00:01:45
2          2020-10-12 00:02:44
                  ...         
4211872    2020-10-16 15:12:35
4211876    2020-10-16 15:16:32
Name: DATE, Length: 4211877, dtype: object
```

In pandas to do this I have used the next two lines of code:

```
CSV_DF['date']=[datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()  for x in CSV_DF['DATE'] ] #date in utc 
CSV_DF2['time']=[datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').time() for x in CSV_DF2['DATE']]# time in utc
```

In Spark, I find how to extract the date field but the extracted time field was not correct. I used the next two lines :

```
CSV_DF = CSV_DF.withColumn("date", func.to_date(func.col("DATE"))) # It was correct I got the correct time
CSV_DF = CSV_DF.withColumn('time', date_format("DATE", 'HH:mm:ss')) # I always got 00:00:00 for each day and it is not correct
```

Is there any other method I could apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Spark columns are not case-sensitive, so your first `withColumn` overwrote the date column. In your second `withColumn`, it is formatting the new date column which has no time information, so you always got 00:00:00.

You can also use `.cast('timestamp')` or `.cast('date')` as shown below. Note that it is not a good idea to use `date_format` with string columns. It works best with timestamp/date columns, but doesn't always work with string columns.

```
df.show()    # date is a string column
+---+-------------------+
| id|               date|
+---+-------------------+
|  0|2020-10-12 00:00:47|
|  1|2020-10-12 00:01:45|
|  2|2020-10-12 00:02:44|
+---+-------------------+

import pyspark.sql.functions  as F

df.select(
    F.col('date').cast('date').alias('date'),
    F.date_format(F.col('date').cast('timestamp'), 'HH:mm:ss').alias('time')
).show()
+----------+--------+
|      date|    time|
+----------+--------+
|2020-10-12|00:00:47|
|2020-10-12|00:01:45|
|2020-10-12|00:02:44|
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: it is the same thing the time is always 00:00:00 for all the values

Comment: @baddy you may have to re-read the dataframe csv_df because you have wiped the original date column

Comment: yes exactly! I re-read it and it is working very well thank you very much I will accept your answer thank you again

Comment: may I know why you said 'It works best with timestamp/date columns, but doesn't always work with string columns.' about date_format

Comment: date_format only works with date strings in standard format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. To convert strings of other date/time formats, use to_timestamp(col, format).